# Cant read my cookie from the root of my site

Tags: javascript

I successfully set a cookie with javascript on one page like this:
..
I went to this article and took the code from it:
**UPDATE :**

```
**http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_cookies.php**
```

The code works.. but I can set and read my cookie from one page only, when I go to the document root , the cookie isnt available there anymore..

I set my cookie when i am in a subfolder of my directory

I am also trying to set it this way:

```
   document.cookie =
      "landing_page_ref=" + encodeURIComponent("FBLND1") +
    "; path=/; " ;
```

but i dont know where i am wrong

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to set a cookie to expire based on closing the browser and have an expiration time. That functionality is determined by the user's browser. If they have it set up to clear their cookies upon closing, then it will delete your cookie regardless of expiration time.

Your best bet would be setting the cookie to a relatively short lifetime (say 30 minutes or so) and refreshing that cookie on each page view. That would allow you to expire the cookie after 30 minutes of inactivity on your site. It's not quite the same thing, but as there's no way to enforce what you're looking for, it's a close second.

Comment: What if I give it 0...  as one of my function arguments... will it delete it less than a day? I took this function from the web.. what does this mean exdate.getDate()... is it days, hours?

Comment: [This is absolutely not true.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie)

Comment: Actually if you omit the expires parameter all together most browsers should trash the cookie upon closing. I apologize for the confusion, but I thought you explicitly wanted to set an expiration time AND have the browser trash it upon closing. After re-reading your post, I don't think that's the case. You can have either, but not both.

Comment: @josh3736 My brain got a little ahead of my fingers there, I'm amending my first line to correct its meaning lol

Comment: I cant read my cookie whenever I am on another page.....why is that.. I took another script from there..http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_cookies.php.. the code works.. but the cookie doesnt exist when I try to read it from the homepage

Comment: You'll need to specify a path when calling that function. Set your path to '/' to force the cookie to be accessible from all pages in the site. The path parameter of a cookie determines the pages which can access it. So setting a cookie to /foo will make that cookie accessible on any page contained within the /foo directory. So /foo/bar/file.html and /foo and /foo/somefile.html will all have access to that cookie. Likewise, setting the path to a single / character will make it work on the whole site. Failure to specify a path will force the cookie to only work for the current page/domain

Answer (score 2):

Session cookies (which are deleted when the browser is closed) are created by not specifying an explicit expiration time.

```
function setSessionCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + escape(value);
}
```

That said, I'd use [a robust cookie library](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to handle cookies rather than trying to roll-my-own.

Answer (score 0):

There are two type of cookies. persistent and session. Use session cookie for it. These cookies expire whenever you close your browser. To convert a persistent cookie to a session cookie just skip expire time.